# Access music on Windows partition while dual-booting Win10/Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, music, rhythmbox

booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. It's running on a 2TB SSHD, and my Ubuntu partition is 250GB. What I'd like to do is be able to access all the many dozens of GBs of music currently stored on the Windows side of my partition when I'm using Ubuntu. Spotify has most of what I need but not all of it.

Is there any way to access the music folder on my Windows 10 partition and have it populate the library of Rhythmbox? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Yes, you just need to mount the windows partition.  Instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: Ubuntu can mount ntfs partitions - as long as they have been safely shutdown (which conflicts which sleep & hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Linux can’t access Win10 system drive because Windows does not fully shut down (it actually hibernates). So you have to choose:

```
Do a full shutdown – When you’re in Windows select “Restart” option or hold the SHIFT key when clicking “Shutdown” option.
or Disable Fast Startup – Launch Control Panel and do:
    navigate to Power Options -> Choose what the power buttons do
    click the link “Change settings that are currently unavailable” at the top
    uncheck the “Turn on fast startup” box under Shutdown settings.
```

1. Fully shutdown Windows 10, or disable Fast Startup
More info here http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/mount-windows-10-in-ubuntu/
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not true.  I have Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.  In both Ubuntu OSes I can't fully access my Windows 10 partition and have access to all my files on it.  When I boot into Win10 I do a regular shutdown or reboot to back into Ubuntu and can still access everything.  I don't have to do a special shutdown in Win10.